# Passing newline character to PowerShell via Cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from Windows cmd.exe.  The input to the PowerShell script is a string, which contains newline characters using PowerShell backtick escaping - i.e:

```
`r`n
```

For demonstration purposes, the input string is then written to the console, and also dumped to a file.

The issue I have is that when the script is run from cmd.exe using the syntax

```
powershell.exe script.ps1 "TEST`r`nTEST"
```

The newline characters in the string are not treated as newline, and are included literally in both the console output and the output text file.

```
TEST`r`nTEST
```

However, if I run this from a PowerShell environment, I get the expected result (i.e. the newline characters are parsed correctly, and a newline is inserted in the appropriate location).

```
TEST
TEST
```

Similarly, if I pass in `\r\n` instead of the escaped newline characters through Windows cmd.exe, and do a `.replace` in the PowerShell script

```
$date = $data.replace("\r\n","`r`n")
```

I get the expected output:

```
TEST
TEST
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on why this happens?

The test script is as follows:

```
param([string]$data) # data to send

Write-Host $data
[IO.File]::WriteAllText('d:\temp.txt', $data)
return 0
```

And the file is called from the command line as:

```
powershell.exe script.ps1 "TEST`r`nTEST"
```

The script is running on Windows Server 2012 R2, using PowerShell v4.0

Comment: As an aside: you probably meant `exit 0` rather than `return 0` - the latter will _output a literal `0`_ rather than set the exit code.

Comment: I'm baffled that your string _isn't_ being interpolated, given that you're not using `-File` and that the default - up to PSv5.1 - is `-Command`. Are you actually using `-File` and only forgot to include it in the question? For instance, if I run `powershell.exe -NoProfile Write-Output "TEST\`r\`nTEST"` in v4, I do get _2_ lines.

Comment: @mklement0 Interestingly, `powershell.exe script.ps1 "TEST'r'nTEST"` does print properly, but `powershell.exe script.ps1 "TEST 'r'nTEST"` only prints the first `TEST`.  I'm not using `-File` in my real example, but I do have spaces.  And when you use `-Write-Output` instead of a script, it prints extra linebreaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use `-Command` and pass the *entire* PowerShell command as a *single string*; e.g.:

```
 C:\> powershell -NoProfile -Command "script.ps1 \"TEST`r`nTEST\""
 TEST
 TEST
```

Note how the internal `"` instances are escaped as `\"`, which PowerShell requires when called from the *outside* (alternatively, for full robustness, use `"^""` (sic) in *Windows PowerShell* and `""` in *PowerShell (Core) v6+*).

<sup>In your *specific* case,

`` powershell -NoProfile -Command script.ps1 "TEST`r`nTEST" `` would have worked too, but generally that only works as intended if the string has no embedded *spaces*.

Given that `-Command` is the *default* up to PSv5.1, your command - as currently posted - should work *as-is*.</sup>

---

As of PowerShell v5.1, arguments passed to `powershell.exe` from the outside:

- **ARE subject to interpretation** by PowerShell, including string interpolation, ***by default* and when you use `-Command`** (i.e., specifying neither `-File` nor `-Command` currently defaults to `-Command`).

  - *Caveat*: The **default behavior will change in v6**: `-File` will be the default then - see the [relevant change on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/4019).
- **are NOT subject to interpretation** if you use **`-File`** to invoke a script - (after potential interpretation by `cmd.exe`) PowerShell treats all arguments as ***literal strings***.

  - *Caveat*: This **behavior is [currently being discussed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4024) with respect to v6**, given that it is overtly problematic in at least one case: trying to pass *Boolean* values.

---

#### Optional reading: Why you should pass the *entire* PowerShell command as a *single* argument when using `-Command`:

When you use `-Command` with *multiple* arguments, PowerShell essentially assembles them into a single command line behind the scenes before executing it.

Any `"..."`-quoting around the individual arguments is *lost* in the process, which can have unexpected results; e.g.:

```
C:\> powershell -NoProfile -Command "& { $args.count }" "line 1`r`nline 2"
3   # !! "line 1`r`nline 2" was broken into 3 arguments
```

Given that the outer `"..."` quoting was removed in the process of parsing the command line, the actual command line that PowerShell ended up executing was:

```
 C:\ PS> & { $args.Count } line 1`r`nline 2
 3
```

To illustrate why, let's look at an equivalent command that uses explicit quoting:

```
 C:\ PS> & { $args.Count } "line"   "1`r`nline"   "2"
```

In other words: After the enclosing `"` were removed, the resulting token was broken into *multiple* arguments by *spaces*, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter will need to be reinterpreted as a PowerShell string. Will this get you down the road?

The reason your `-replace` did not work is that the original string actually contains a backtick. It needs to be escaped in the search string.

```
C:\src\t>type p1.ps1
Param([string]$s)

Write-Host $s

$p = Invoke-Expression `"$s`"
Write-Host $p

$p2 = $s -replace "``r``n","`r`n"
Write-Host $p2


C:\src\t>powershell -noprofile -file .\p1.ps1 "TEST`r`nTEST"
TEST`r`nTEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I personally prefer passing in \r\n and then just doing a replace in PowerShell with 'r'n.  I was more curious about _why_ this happens when invoked from cmd.  For example, if you pass in 'r'n and then replace 'r'n with 'r'n, the 'r'n is still output literally, and if you append 'r'n to the string inside PowerShell, the appended 'r'n get output as a newline (but the existing ones are still output literally).  I just can't make sense of the logic behind it.

Comment: Good catch about not escaping the escape string.  I suppose it does answer the question.  I was just hoping there was a more philosophical reason why it does this from cmd.

Comment: Sorry that I could not make it more philosophical. I'm just glad that you understand. It would be difficult to explain to someone who did not already understand what an escape character was.

Comment: be very careful with this script - this gives the person passing the variable to the script the ability to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Hence the preference for the replace option

Answer (score 1):

Carriage return and Linefeed are bytes with values 13 and 10, you can't write them, you can't see them.

As a convenience, when writing PowerShell code, the language will let you write:

```
"`r`n"
```

in a double quoted string, and when processing PowerShell source code (and at no other time), it will read those and replace them with bytes value 13 and 10.

It is [this line of code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/tokenizer.cs#L1241) in the PowerShell tokenizer which does it.

There is nothing special about backtick-n to the cmd.exe interpreter, and nothing special about having it in a string - you can put it there in a single quoted string

```
'`n'
```

or replacing it in a string - except that you have to note when the replacement happens. e.g. in your comment:

> For example, if you pass in 'r'n and then replace 'r'n with 'r'n, the 'r'n is still output literally

Because your code

```
-replace "`r`n"
```

becomes

```
-replace "[char]13[char]10"
```

and your string passed in from outside contains

```
`r`n
```

and they don't match. Backtick-n in a string isn't magic, strings are not all interpreted by the PowerShell engine as PowerShell code, nor are parameters, or anything. And it's only in that context - when you write your -replace code, that is when the swap for *actual newline characters* happens.